# Autocomplete with unexpected arrow key (keydown) event and mouse event behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an autocomplete menu that I trying to set it up in a way that it responds to both `mouse` and `keydown` events.  The problem rises when I hit the arrow keys after having hovered over one of the items in the menu.  When I hit the up arrow key altering hovering over an item, rather than its usual behavior of moving up one item it *moves up 2 items*.  When I hit the down arrow key after hovering over an item with the mouse, *it takes 2 key strokes to move*.

**My HTML:**

```html
<body><form action="/stocks/portfolio/" method="get" class="well" style="width:50%">
<div class="input-group" style="width:50%">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Quote" name="q" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div id="auto" class="list-group" style="display:none;position:absolute;width:50%"></div>

 <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```js
var itemSel = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var result = $("input[name='q']");
    var autoComplete = $('#auto');
    result.keydown(function(event) {
        var liLength = autoComplete.children('a').length;
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (liLength > 0) {
                autoComplete.children('a:nth-child(' + itemSel + ')').removeClass('hover');
                itemSel++;
                autoComplete.children('a:nth-child(' + itemSel + ')').addClass('hover');
                //
                if (itemSel > liLength) {
                    itemSel--;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (liLength > 0) {
                autoComplete.children().removeClass('hover');
                itemSel--;
                autoComplete.children('a:nth-child(' + itemSel + ')').addClass('hover');
                if (itemSel < 0) {
                    itemSel++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    autoComplete.on('mouseover', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
       autoComplete.children().not($(this)).removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        itemSel = $(this).index()
    }).on('mouseout', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        itemSel = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe a shorter questions will get you a lot of answers, people here don't have a lot of spare time to read all of you're code. Could you please short the question (and code) a little bit?

Comment: @gpopoteur I figured out the problem, it was just through research that I realized how the `nth-child` selector works, as described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I Realized the mistake I made—the `nth-child` selector for whatever reason starts at 1, not 0, I corrected the the assigning of the `itemSel` variable to by the return value of the jQuery `.index()` and added 1